# How to show all available Routes at specific URL

Tags: javascript, api, url, tree

Is there a command (e.g. via Curl or other) or a script that can expose all API routes when I hit specific URL?

Reason is that for a new project - there is no docs for all routes that are on a remote server but would like to see what is available.

Something like 'tree' command in bash would be perfect.

Comment: Not unless the API itself supplies such a list.  Imagine hitting `https://gooogle.com` and expecting it to tell you everything that's available.

Comment: That would be awesome! :)

Comment: Yes, and terrifying all at once!